# Reverse order in HTML div element

Tags: html, css, python-sphinx

I am trying to modify the style code of my sphinx documentation with the spinx_rtd_theme.

Is it possible to set up the `img-tag` with the logo.png to the top inside the element `a.icon-home` per CSS without changing of the html code?

```
<div class="wy-side-nav-search" style="background: #E20074">
  <a href="#" class="icon icon-home"> 
   testproject
  <img src="_static/logo.png" class="logo" alt="Logo">
 </a>           
 <div class="version">
  0.1
 </div>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the a tag as such:

```
a {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

will work.  Further explanation is here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-direction/

> > The flex-direction property is a sub-property of the Flexible Box
> >     Layout module.
> >
> > It establishes the main-axis, thus defining the direction flex items
> >     are placed in the flex container.
> >
> > Reminder: the main axis of a flex container is the primary axis along
> >     which flex items are laid out. Beware, it is not necessarily
> >     horizontal; it depends on the flex-direction property.
> >
> > The flex-direction property accepts 4 different values:
> >
> > row (default): same as text direction  row-reverse: opposite to text > direction  column: same as row but top to bottom  column-reverse: same as row-reverse top to bottom Note that row and row-reverse are
> >     affected by the directionality of the flex container. If its text
> >     direction is ltr, row represents the horizontal axis oriented from
> >     left to right, and row-reverse from right to left; if the direction is
> >     rtl, it's the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox` layout model to achive this.

First, set `icon`'s `display` property to `flex`.

```
.icon {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Then:

```
.icon img {
    order: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display the icon-home as flex and then change its direction with the css attribute [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)

```
.icon-home {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```